# Identifying Mignovich village in Russia/Belarus?

Tags: russia, place-names, belarus

I am trying to find information on my paternal grandfather's line, he immigrated to the US from Mignovich or Mignovichi village in Belarus in the early 1900's, we are looking for ancestors there? He said it was near Poland, and talked about Grodno.

Comment: Based on [this article](http://daily.grodno.co/2014/08/western-belarusians-in-poland-and.html), the village of Mihnovich is now known as Byaroza and is located in the Brest region. I wasn't able to find any other reference to it, sorry.

Comment: Very interesting, but there is such village Mignovichi, located in Smolensk region, on the left shore of river Grodnya https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8
Could it be coincidence?

Answer (score 4):

I took a look at the [Słownik geograficzny Królestwa Polskiego i innych krajów słowiańskich](http://dir.icm.edu.pl/Slownik_geograficzny/Tom_XV_cz.2/322) (Geographic Dictionary of the Kingdom of Poland and Other Slavic Countries) to see if I could find a town with a similar name. In the area of Grodno there is the town Michnowce:

[image: Michnowce]

The image below shows it relative to Grodno:
[image: Michnowce relative to Grodno]

The images above are from [kresy](http://www.kami.net.pl/kresy/), which is a site dedicated to the Eastern Borderlands of pre-world war II Poland.

Nonetheless, you may want to take a look through the pages of the Słownik to see if there is another town with a similar name.